# Angular js post/get in nested ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a table of info generated by ng-repeat. 
I want to add a feature to each row of table which gives user ability to see more detail of that specific record. I added another ng-model which gets the key of that row and asks server for more detail. 
But controller cannot read this ng-model. my code is as below:

HTML:

```
<html ng-app = "myApp">
<head>
...
</head>
<body>
    ...
    <div ng-controller = "AppCtrl">
    ...
        <content>
            <div class="general_detail">
                <div ng-model = "docParam.docNo"></div>
                <div class = "dialog" ng-repeat = 'doc in doclist'>
                    <table class = "detail">
                        <tbody>
                        ...
                        <tr>
                            ...
                            <td style="text-align: right">
                                <div ng-model = "docDetail.docNo"></div>
                                <a href="" ng-click="docDetail.docNo = doc.NO; docDetailP()" >More...</a>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div ng-repeat = 'd in detailView'>
                                    <p>
                                        Rev : {{d.REV_NO}}
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        ...
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </content>
        ...
</body>
</html>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.docDetailP = function() { 
    $http.post('/docQuery', $scope.docDetail);
    docDetailG();
};

var docDetailG = function() {
    $http.get('/docDetails').then(function(response) {
        $scope.detailView = response.data;
    });
};
```

Thanks in advance for your solutions.

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

These are the errors which you made,

1. `<div ng-model = "docParam.docNo"></div>`
           ng-model will work for form elements
2. why do you assign `docDetail.docNo = doc.NO;` and then call the method. Instead you can pass as a parameter
3. Change the way of posting the value `$http.post('/docQuery', $scope.docDetail);`.

Have a look at the modified code.

**HTML**

```
<content>
    <div class="general_detail">
        <div ng-model = "docParam.docNo"></div>
        <div class = "dialog" ng-repeat = 'doc in doclist'>
            <table class = "detail">
                <tbody>
                ...
                <tr>
                    ...
                    <td style="text-align: right">
                        <div ng-model = ""></div>
                        <a href="" ng-click="docDetailP(doc.NO)" >More...</a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div ng-repeat = 'd in detailView'>
                            <p>
                                Rev : {{d.REV_NO}}
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                ...
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</content>
```

Your controller should be like

```
$scope.docDetailP=function (number) {
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/docQuery',

        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        data: number

    })
    .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        successcallback(data); 
    })
    .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        $log.warn(data, status, headers, config);
    })
    $scope.docDetailG();
}
```

Be careful that my solution assumes that the web service endpoint recieves a number.

Comment: Thanks Aravind, I changed some part of the code to have json format for data. Also removed @scope from docDetailG(). My other issue is that when docDetail retrieves detailView, this information is repeated for all items of doclist however I want to have them only for a specific index. Any idea about that?

Comment: yes bro, my first question was answered perfectly. But my code is not complete yet as retrieved data does not sit in the correct index of the main array

Comment: do u need further help??

Comment: yes please, i need to update Rev : {{d.REV_NO}} as per retrieved data of detailView in clicked index of doclist.

Comment: @FaridFarzin for each click you want to update? REV_NO or ? how ?